# Git repository with symbolic links

Tags: node.js, angular, git, github

I feel like I'm doing something wrong here (architecture-wise I know I am, but this is a simple project).

There are two ("three") sub-projects, living in the same folder (`proj`):

1. An Angular frontend (`proj/fe`)
2. A Typescript (node.js) based backend (`proj/lambda`)
3. A shared "domain" directory that contains the DTOs (`proj/domain`)

From what I understand, in an ideal world, this would be three separate repos, with #3 being a git submodule of #1 and #2.

But this is a tiny project, and I am not in an ideal world, so I need to keep everything in the same git repo.

The current setup is that the "domain" directory (sub-project #3) is presented to both #1 and #2 via symlinks; i.e. `proj/fe/src/app/domain` and `proj/lambda/code/domain` both point to  `proj/domain`.

Git doesn't seem to handle this scenario very well out of the box.

Is there an option or flag (or a better method -- *without* resolving to using mutliple repos) that I can utilize here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` knows how to store and checkout symlinks, the thing is it stores the *exact path you provided* for your symlink.

(do double check if you are running Windows though)

---

Your setup should work if you provide *relative paths* for your symlinks (and if these path do not escape the repo) :

```bash
cd proj/
ln -nsf ../../../domain fe/src/app/domain
ln -nsf ../../domain lambda/code/domain

# on any checkout: the symlinks will point to that directory, two or
# three levels higher than current directory
```

If you used absolute paths instead:

```bash
ln -nsf /path/to/proj/domain fe/src/app/domain
ln -nsf /path/to/proj/domain lambda/code/domain
```

The checked out symlink will point to `/path/to/proj/domain` -- which is not what you want on a system other than your dev laptop.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was using absolute paths and that was the reason it wasn't working.